# What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have just booted my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM and tried to install some application with `sudo apt install`.

But got error message:

> `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`
>       `E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?
How to gently stop it and take manual control on APT?

Comment: Did you use sudo?

Comment: Of course, I have used sudo :)

Comment: It's probably `unattended-upgrade`. If you auto-install any updates, it will do it.

Comment: Perhaps try `pgrep`ping for apt or unattended-upgrade, or use `fuser` on the lock file?

Comment: Try running this command to find the process **ps aux | grep -i apt**

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks, but... I really hate scrolling of code blocks here on AskUbuntu, so I use block quote for visual contrast and backticks to prevent scrolling. We have already [discussed this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18054/66509) on meta without positive results. Real text or even graphical terminal does not have horizontal scrolling! But I agree about tags.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for letting me know your perspective. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As was recommended in comments - I have checked the owner of the file

```
$ sudo fuser -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend:
                     root       2112 F.... unattended-upgr

$ ps aux | grep 2112
root      2112 66.5  8.1 366108 113508 ?       Sl   13:03   0:28 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade --download-only

$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
unattended-upgrades: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
```

So this file was created by `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade` from `unattended-upgrades` package. I can kill it with:

```
sudo kill -KILL 2112
```

and take control with

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-purge unattended-upgrades
```

as I forgot to purge it on this VM.

---

**Note: do not purge *unattended upgrades* on your system if unsure. It needs some time to finish (depends on internet connection speed and disk speed) and then you can use APT as usual.**

Comment: You might want to add that unattended-upgrades only needs a bit time and then the lock file will be gone without any interaction.

Comment: The question asks for gently stopping the process but the KILL signal does kill it immediately. You should use the default TERM signal instead, see [`man kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html#DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Debian bullseye 11.0, no Internet connection, the unattended-upgrade process is interminable but by `sudo kill -9 <pid>`. Even if there is a local mirror configured in sources.list, it isn't smart enough to use it. I  keep a local debian mirror for i386, and amd64 platforms, because it actually uses less bandwidth than using a remote mirror for many machines. It's also good if you want to get an install done without exposing it to the Internet before routine hardening is complete.