# Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - specific to one single .deb package

Tags: apt, dpkg, lock

I have a custom built package I'm trying to install on my device.

It returns this error:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i MyPackage.deb 
(Reading database ... 181574 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../MyPackage.deb ...
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
dpkg: error processing archive MyPackage.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 100
```

I already tried all the traditional ways to remove a lock:

- [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)
- [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)
- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)
- [What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114678/what-process-created-the-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-file-in-ubuntu)

None of those worked for me. I do not find any running process related to *lock* or *lock-frontend* files. I tried "ps", "fuser", "lsof" .. **I also noticed this problem is related to this specific package. Any other version of this same package or any other package is installed correctly and does not trigger any error.**

Any idea ?

Comment: I used `ps -aux | grep apt` to find the offender.

Comment: Have you tried installing the package by clicking on the package and selecting the software center to open and install the package? Also, how did you try to determine if there is a process using the lock file? Did you use `htop` or did you use `ps` or something else?

Comment: Also, what package are you trying to install?

Comment: Could you please share file-list from your `MyPackage.deb` package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114678/what-process-created-the-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-file-in-ubuntu)

Comment: To answer all your comments I updated my description. I tried various ways to detect which process is locking the flag but did not find anything. The package I'm trying to install is a build of the Intel libRealsense library for arm64 architecture: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this problem.

One of the install scripts was corrupted into MyPackage.deb (the package I was trying to install). As a result, the install was exiting creating this confusing message.

Thanks for your help