# unattended-upgrade taking a lot of CPU power

Tags: process, cpu-load, unattended-upgrades

I've recently upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 16 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it's been a few days that the process unattended-upgrade is taking a lot of CPU power, forcing my fan to be quite noisy (cf screenshot)

[image]

Do you know what this process do, why it is always running and why it is so greedy in terms of CPU power? (What could it be possibly doing with all this calculation power?) Is it safe shutting it down?

Many thanks in advance for your help! :-)

EDIT: I tried to upgrade apt-get and i got the following message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Can't use sudo anymore, could unattended-process be using sudo? if so why for so long?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of  the following command: `ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire most recent day of activity show in the following logfile: `/var/log/apt/term.log`

Comment: Since we don't know which timezone you are in, please also add your current output of the command `date`. This will help us gauge how old the other output is,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114678/what-process-created-the-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-file-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: can you run `sudo /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d` to see what it is doing

Comment: I had this issue also and the workaround I used is to kill the process several times with the command `sudo killall unattended-upgrade` until it was definitely killed. Then the update manager started correctly automatically and I was able to install updates without high CPU usage.