# Can't install rstudio in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04

I am new to linux and ubuntu. I am trying to install Rstudio on ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.1) but 2.35-0ubuntu3 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.1)
             Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How do I downgrade dependencies for libc6-dev?

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and see if that fixes it. `apt` (and `apt-get`) need to be ran with `sudo` so they have root privileges

Comment: Thanks @cocomac. I am still having the same problem. {sudo apt install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.34-0ubuntu3.2) but 2.35-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libstdc++-9-dev : Depends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What process created the /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114678/what-process-created-the-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-file-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the fact that, so far, there is no stable release that supports Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. See discussion on RStudio Community:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-ide-desktop-2022-02-0-443-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-some-gui-issue/135876/4

Apparently, latest daily builds work, at least with some tweaking to options. I have yet to try myself but I'm planning to. I'd love to hear how it goes for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could solve that by starting rstudio with the --no-sandbox option. The even better news is that the latest rstudio release is out with a package for 22.04. For me, that upgrade solved the issue.